# Is Chinese government using Huawei to spy on the USA and the West?

Tags: united-states, china

- A while ago Trump said that the Chinese government uses Chinese tech giant Huawei's telecom network and equipment to spy on the USA and the West.
- Secretary of state Pompeo also said that Chinse made chips have backdoors and these backdoors enable the Chinese government to spy on other countries' military resources.

Is that a truth?

Comment: The answer may be an unsatisfying "it's plausible either way and there's no publicly available evidence."

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/is-huawei-the-front-for-a-chinese-espionage-attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44157/does-the-chinese-government-officially-have-access-to-it-equipment-sold-abroad